# Add buttons in a drawer menu's footer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I would like to add those buttons under a drawer menu

[image: drawerMenu]

those are my xml files:

(layout/activity_main)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

(menu/activity_main_drawer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_log"
            android:title="Log-in" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_preferiti"
            android:title="Preferiti" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_maps"
            android:title="Mappa" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_terms"
            android:title="Termini e condizioni" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_who"
            android:title="Chi Siamo" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:title="Impostazioni" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tutorial"
            android:title="Tutorial" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

I tried to use a linearlayout with gravity bottom (or end) but it remained at the top

Answer (score 8):

Try to place additional views inside your `NavigationView`, something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <!--Here is a container at the bottom of navigation drawer. Place your images here-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

In your **menu/activity_main_drawer**

Add the following after the group

```
<item android:title="">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
            android:title="Follow us:"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/share"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

and **your_custom_layout.xml** may be like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with the help of constraint layout

[image: I solve it this way]